# Comment traduire « you hear a low chanting drone » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

Il s'agit d'une simple difficulté de traduction. Le contexte est fort simple; je suis dans un donjon et j'avance dans un passage, puis tout à coup :

> You hear a [low](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/low) [chanting](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/chanting) [drone](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/drone).

Donc essentiellement quelque chose de *faible*, produit par la *voix* et l'idée du  « bourdonnement ». Ça ne provient pas directement du passage, plus probablement d'une pièce adjacente; c'est peut-être les membres d'une secte qui tiennent un rituel quelconque (comme par exemple dans les premières secondes de cet [extrait](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiE5mE0ZorA)). Mais que faire de tout ça en contexte ? *Google* suggère le poétique « *vous entendez un [drone](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/drone/26865?q=drone#26732) chantant faible* ». Ma tentative :

> Vous entendez un faible bruit de gens qui chantent.

Mais est-ce que tout le sens est rendu, incluant le *bourdonnement* ? Qui dit mieux (et pourquoi) ?

Comment: La traduction des chants en anglais. Traduire « drone », « hum » et tous leurs compères. On croit le français riches, mais dans ce domaine comme dans celui des expressions, ils ont toute une palette de nuances difficiles. [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/drone) donne le bourdonnement et j'avoue en être assez partisan : le bruit est encore trop faible pour reconnaître des voix, ce n'est qu'un bruit qui monte et descend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sur [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/chanting)

> **chanting**       psalmodie *nf*

Et comme [drone](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/drone#Anglais) est un faible bourdonnement, un léger ronronnement, en s'inspirant du verbe qui veut dire :

> - Ronronner
> - Marmonner, parler d’une voix monotone.

Et étant donné le contexte du donjon remplis de monstre, je pencherais pour une traduction par :

> Vous entendez faiblement psalmodier des incantations, prenez garde...

ou

> Vous entendez faiblement la litanie d'une incantation au loin

ou si tu préfères garder *"low"* attaché au groupe nominal

> Vous entendez la faible litanie d'une incantation

ou

> La musique d'une incantations vous parvient faiblement

ou encore, si ton donjon est une ruche

> Le bourdonnement d'un groupe d'abeilles géantes vous parvient faiblement

Answer (score 3):

Ici je pense que la nuance de bourdonnement n'est pas importante. Le mot « *drone* » désigne un bruit faible et indistinct, trop faible par exemple pour qu'on entende les paroles du chant. Il est donc naturel de ne pas chercher une traduction qui rende exactement ce mot. Par ordre d'importance :

- il y a un bruit (*drone*) ;
- ce bruit est relativement faible (*low*, *drone*) ;
- il s'agit d'une ou plusieurs personnes qui chantent (*chanting*) ;
- mais « *chanting* » n'est pas n'importe quel chant (ce n'est pas « *singing* », c'est plutôt du sprechgesang ;
- le bruit est continu (*-ing* dans ce contexte) ;
- le bruit est d'origine lointaine (*low*, *drone*) ;
- le bruit ressemble à un bourdonnement (*drone*).

J'aime bien la proposition de « litanie d'une incantation » de [Yohann V.](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14078). Ça a une connotation religieuse que l'original anglais n'a pas, mais elle est probablement justifiée, et je trouve « litanie » tout seul pas naturel. Comme « *chanting drone* » indique un bruit continue, je pense qu'il s'agit plutôt d'une série ou d'une répétition d'incantations.

> Un bruit lointain d'incantations parvient à vos oreilles.
>
> Vous entendez une litanie chantée dans le lointain.

Answer (score 1):

Pour sortir du mot à mot :

> Le murmure d'un drone arrive à vos oreilles.
>
> Un léger bruissement révèle un drone (dans le contexte, il ne peut être ouï que par vous).

S'il ne s'agit pas d'un jeu informatique qui se passerait de nos jours, mais d'une évocation médiévale, le *bourdonnement* manifestation sonore du *faux bourdon* (drone en anglais) est de rigueur :

> Un faible bourdonnement vous arrive aux oreilles.
>
> Le bourdonnement d'un chant monotone vous parvient.

Comment: Je crois qu'on parle d'un monde médiéval (donjon) et donc *"drone"* n'est pas un drone mais un son ronronnant, bourdonnant.

Comment: @YohannV. J'ai complété ma réponse à la suite de vos remarques